# How to add new Column for Image in BlogEngine.NET?

Tags: blogengine.net

I am trying to use BlogEngine.Net for my website. I need to display an image per post on Post List page. There's no separate column that supports such functionality. I need to know that is this possible & how?

If this isn't possible then I need to scan the HTML text to find the first image, for this I need to write my own custom Pager code. I am using this for first time. Can anyone guide me in write direction how this should be done in BlogEngine.Net.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I considered using a custom field for adding an image URL to the post, but that's not very user friendly.